# MAC can't access SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, dns, mac-os-x, network

I created an Intranet environment (SharePoint 2013) for my company and i can't connect MAC users to the intranet. My company use a domain but users can access the site without being in domain by using "NetBios over TCP/IP". For MAC users that option is not availble, so i find myself unable to connect them to the SharePoint environment. Can someone help me with this?